# Python library using parent method instead of overriden method

Tags: python, inheritance

I have extended the `Parent` class with the `Override` class. I have have overridden the `method()` method to fix a bug that occurs in the `Parent` class. I fixed the said bug and this fix has been tested in the `Override` class.

I use the `Override` class through an `External` class. By testing the `External` class to see if the previous bug is fixed, I discovered that it is not and that the traceback does not go through the `Override` class.

```
class Parent():

    def method(self, param):
        # Bugged
        do_stuff()

class Override(Parent):

    def method(self, param):
        # Fixed (tested)
        param = fix_param(param)
        super(Parent, self).method(param)

class External():

    def processing():
        # Same bug as in `Parent`
        param = get_param()
        obj = Override()
        obj.method(param)
```

It seems to me that the `External` class uses the `Parent.method()` method instead of the `Override.method()` method. Any clue on how to fix it or on where this problem comes from?

I'm a beginner and have not been confronted inheritance a lot so, please, forgive my ignorance and my lack of experience.

**EDIT**

Test that fails in `External` :

```
import os
import collections
import envtpl
from acquisition.configargparse_confparser import StepConfigFileParser
from configparser_extended import ExtendedConfigParser
from unittest import TestCase
from acquisition.utils import set_custom_environment


class ConfigFileParserTestCase(TestCase):

def test_parse_extended(self):
    # x = StepConfigFileParser("test_plugin_name", "test")
    plugin_name = "test_plugin_name"
    step_name = "test"
    set_custom_environment(plugin_name, step_name)
    config = os.environ.get('MFCONFIG', 'GENERIC')
    filename = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "/test.ini"
    with open(filename, 'r') as stream:
        config_parser = ExtendedConfigParser(
            config=config, inheritance='im', interpolation=None)
        content = stream.read()
        config_parser.read_string(content)  # Fails here
        section = "step_%s" % step_name
        res = collections.OrderedDict()
        for key in config_parser.options(section):
            if not key.startswith('arg_'):
                continue
            res[key.replace('arg_', '', 1)] = envtpl.render_string(
                config_parser.get(section, key))
    self.assertEqual(res, {"venom": "snake", "revolver": "ocelot"})
```

Overridden method :
`read_string()` in https://github.com/thefab/configparser_extended/blob/master/configparser_extended/ecp.py line 573

Parent method :
`read_string()` from `configparser`
(https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.read_string)

`test.ini`

```
[step_test]
arg_venom=snake
arg_revolver=ocelot
liquid=snake
```

Error :

```
ERROR: test_parse_extended (tests.test_confparser.ConfigFileParserTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/florian/metwork/mfdata/src/acquisition/tests/test_confparser.py", line 39, in test_parse_extended
    config_parser.read_string(content)
  File "/opt/metwork-mfext/opt/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/backports/configparser/__init__.py", line 728, in read_string
    sfile = io.StringIO(string)
TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not str
```

Comment: You need to show real code and the error you get. The code you've posted would not demonstrate the behaviour you claim.

Comment: Please post a MCVE.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not a complete working example, but it should do as you suggest.

Here is an example you can run to prove the point:

```
class Parent():
    def method(self):
        print('parent')

class Child(Parent):    
    def method(self):
        print('child')

class Other():
    def call_method(self):
        c = Child()
        c.method()

o = Other()
o.call_method()
```

That prints 'child', proving the Child class has overridden method(self).

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: Yes, that's the behaviour I would expect, but it seems to use the parent method in my case and I don't understand why.